# Problem in estimating parameters by moments methods

Tags: r, mathematical-statistics, estimation, inference

I am working on one of the discrete probability distribution having pmf as

$P(x)=\{p^{\log(1+x^c)}\}-\{p^{\log(1+(x+1)^c)}\},\quad 0<p<1; c>0; \,x=0,1,2,...$

The moments of the distribution are not in the closed form as

First moment about origin is

$\mu_1= \sum_{x=1}^\infty (p^{\log(1+x^c)})$.

$\mu_2= \sum_{x=1}^\infty[(x^2-(x-1)^2)(p^{\log(1+x^c)})]$.

Now I want to apply moments method for parameter estimation. My sample has first moment=2.3 and 2nd moment=3.

Now I have two non linear equations as by equating population moments to sample moments

$\sum_{x=1}^\infty (p^{\log(1+x^c)})=2.3$

$\sum_{x=1}^\infty[(x^2-(x-1)^2)(p^{\log(1+x^c)})] =3$

Now I am interested in finding these estimates of p and c in R software but I am a bit confused how to handle such situation. Or is there any other procedure to follow.

Comment: Your equations contain no $q$ so you can't estimate that from data.

Comment: Since your distribution has a closed form cdf, $F(x)=1-\{p^{\log(1+(x+1)^c)}\}$, you should write your moment equations in terms of quantiles rather than standard moments.

Comment: @ Glen_b, sorry it is p, not q

Comment: @ Xi'an, Could you please explain it a bit more, how to approach this